# Needs to tap twice to fire onPress function in ListItem when keyboard is open in react native

Tags: react-native

Below is my code I am facing issue where when I clicking on list item `onPress` , it does not work for first time when the keyboard is open so I need to tap twice to order to work it, any help is appreciated.

```
<FlatList
   data={this.state.users}
   renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
     <ListItem
     title={item.userName}
     onPress={item => this.sendRequestToTheUser(item)}
     containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }} />)}

     keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
     extraData={this.state.userName} />
```

Comment: https://medium.com/react-native-training/todays-react-native-tip-keyboard-issues-in-scrollview-8cfbeb92995b

Answer (score 7):

You should use `keyboardShouldPersistTaps=always` prop on your FlatList. As RN [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps) says:

> The keyboard will not dismiss automatically, and the scroll view will not catch taps, but children of the scroll view can catch taps.

So you will be able to tap your buttons just once no matter if keyboard is open.

 There's also a [medium](https://medium.com/react-native-training/todays-react-native-tip-keyboard-issues-in-scrollview-8cfbeb92995b) post that explains how to resolve common keyboard issues on React Native (which also contains `Problem 1: Button needs to be tapped twice`)

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
<FlatList 
     ...
     keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always' //open keyboard
     keyboardDismisssMode='on-drag' //auto close keyboard 
/>
```

goodluck!