# How can I enable touch on other part of screen while my soft keyboard is open in my cordova app ( based on react JS )?

Tags: reactjs, cordova

I do able to find solutions for react native but I need specific answer for either react or cordova.

This is the solution for react native ***keyboardShouldPersistTaps=always***
This is the reference to the answer which is for react native.
[Needs to tap twice to fire onPress function in ListItem when keyboard is open in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52426805/needs-to-tap-twice-to-fire-onpress-function-in-listitem-when-keyboard-is-open-in/52427098)

Thanks in advance.